# Bitbucket repo:push webhook to drone fails

Tags: bitbucket, ngrok, drone.io

I'm trying to test drone for implementing CD in my java environment. I'm running drone 0.4 locally and exposing publicly through ngrok.

I have managed to add some bitbucket private git repositories to drone. There is already a `drone.yml` file in the repo. Drone has successfully registered webhooks in these repositories. But when the webhook is invoked, drone is responding with status code `404`.

When looking at the drone logs y see the following error message:

```
http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
time="2016-09-02T10:54:29Z" level=error msg="failure to get build config for organization/repository. " 
time="2016-09-02T10:54:29Z" level=error msg="Error #01: \n" ip=104.192.143.193 latency=5.693494398s method=POST path="/hook" status=404 time="2016-09-02T10:54:29Z" user-agent="Bitbucket-Webhooks/2.0"
```

I have seen some posts talking about case problems with repository names. In my case the real repository name is `Organization/repository` with the first letter of the organization name in uppercase. Whereas the logs are showing lowercase.

Any idea on how to proceed solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really stupid solution. Just leaving a response instead of closing in case another drone newbie comes through the same blindness.

The name of the drone build file must be `.drone.yml` and not `drone.yml`